# How to cross compile qt for embedded linux in QT Creator Open Source version

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, embedded-linux

I want to cross compile my QT Application to Toradex embedded linux platform. The QT Creator Commercial version comes with in-built compiler for embedded linux but open source doesn't.

So, is there any way to compile and run it on embedded linux.

Comment: Did you take a look at their existing documentation [here](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux)? It should already be all there.

Comment: @SanchayanMaity It is for QT commercial version not for Community version.

Comment: The one which can be included with [Yocto/OE](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux#Build_with_OpenEmbedded_Layers) is not the commercial version.

Answer (score 4):

```
After some research, I finally get a way to do it. Here are the steps:

1. Download QT Creator and Install

2. Download QT Everywhere
https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.8/5.8.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.8.0.tar.gz.mirrorlist

3. Extract It

4. Change path to path/to/qt-everywhere

5. Configure qt-everywhere

    ./configure -release -device linux-imx7-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi- -sysroot /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebkit -skip qtwebkit-examples -prefix /usr/local/qt5-imx

(QT will save on the location listed in prefix, i.e here /usr/local/qt5-imx)

6. Open QT Creator

7. Goto Tools->Options, Add Compiler
-> Add GCC Compiler, add path /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++

8. Add QT Version:
path: /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/usr/local/qt5-imx/bin/qmake

9. Add Debugger :
path: /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gdb

10. Add Kit
-> Select Generic Linux Device:
-> Specify GCC compiler and debugger path, which is created above
-> Add Sysroot location: /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots
-> Add QT Version: select qt version, created above
-> Apply and Close
```

Comment: You seem to be using SDK build by OE based on your toolchain. Why not use the meta-qt5 layer for Qt support?